# Where is the source to embedding-projector-standalone?

Tags: tensorflow, visualization

I'm able to run the Tensorflow Projector as a [standalone 3d viewer](https://github.com/tensorflow/embedding-projector-standalone). There is some very minimal documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/embedding_viz/). Running standalone is as simple as

```
$ git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/embedding-projector-standalone
$ cd embedding-projector-standalone
$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

However,

1. I don't see any source code in this repo. How is [oss_demo_bin.js](https://github.com/tensorflow/embedding-projector-standalone/blob/master/oss_demo_bin.js) generated, and how can I fork it?
2. I don't understand the tensors (`.bytes`) file format which are associated with each labels (`.tsv`) file. What is the spec for the `bytes` files in the [sample data directory](https://github.com/tensorflow/embedding-projector-standalone/tree/master/oss_data)?

Answer (score -1):

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/tree/master/tensorboard/plugins/projector

This can launch the standalone, so I assume it's possible to also build it from this.

Comment: @entreprenerds A link seems appropriate to answer a question about where on the Internet something is stored